# Ionic v3 reed more/less

Tags: ionic-framework

I need help.. How can I show more words if something is longer than 20 characters?

```
<ion-list no-padding no-border no-margin>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items | async | reverse">
    <ion-card no-padding no-border>
    <img [src]="item.url" />
  <ion-row>
    <ion-item ion-start class="font">{{item.descrizione}}</ion-item>
  </ion-row>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Now if {{item.descrizione}} is too long it simply doesn't show more. I thought that *ngIf {{item-descrizione.length}} > 20 could solve my problem but I don't know how to continue with show more/less text.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share with us your JSON file (i.e the `items` array) ?

Comment: It's a firebase database I'm working with.. Everythings works well but I don't know how to send you a screenshot

Comment: That's fine either, just share whatever results you get as I want to see `descrizione` if exists in the array and in all the other objects

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/7stMR) Every other object has the same structure

Comment: Are you sure that all `descrizione` values are not empty in all the other objects ? I can make a decision based on a screenshot, I need to see the full JSON object, I guess that an object has an empty `descrizione` value

Comment: So you are right, not all field now are filled but that's because my app is still alpha so I don't use every fields all the time.. Does it make any difference? Because I don't know if final users will use evry field all the time I prefer to have some empty [link](https://imgur.com/a/d0sR8)

Comment: Well, that's the issue then, when `item.descrizione` is empty, it has nothing to show.

Comment: Let me explain better.. I know that if item.descrizione is empty, nothing will show up. My question is how can I show only the begin of item.descrizione and then with a button expand the text area to show all

Answer (score 1):

What about using pipes? This is something what I have done.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'truncate'
})
export class TruncatePipe {
  transform(value: string, args: string[]) : string {
    let limit = args.length > 0 ? parseInt(args[0], 10) : 10;
    let trail = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : '...';

    return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
  }
}
```

and Component class and template goes something like this

```
 export class TruncatedTextComponent {
      limit: number = 40;
      truncating = true;
    }

    <div *ngIf="text">
    <div *ngIf="text.length <= limit">{{text}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="truncating && text.length > limit">
      {{text | truncate : limit}}
      <button ion-button (click)="truncating = false">show more</button>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!truncating && text.length > limit">
      {{text}}
      <button ion-button (click)="truncating = true">show less</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In newer versions of angular, transform args would be written this way (value: string, ...args: string[]). Without the 3 dots before args, it won't work.